# Accessing the Magento 2 Components Manager

Tags: magento

Out of one of the most frustrating testing experience, I would like to ask the following question.

We're trying to understand how Mangento extensions work. We're using a Dockerized setup and running the 2.1.0 version of Magento.

We're desperately trying to install a random extension, and we find our-self unable to find the so called "Components Manager".

We've tied following the Magento Documentation, but our installed version doesn't look like it's the same - the docs might be seriously outdated.

The documentation we're following is http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/module-man/compman-start.html .

In our Admin panel, there is no such thing as "Web Setup Wizard" in "Setup".

Where is the documentation, how do you install the simplest extension into Magento 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to install the extension in magento 2

```
1. Using composer
2. Using file transfer
```

For details : 
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-extensions-in-magento2

Comment: Unfortunatelly, as stated in my original question, the Admin panel doesn't offer the options mentioned here. I'm sure this is linked to how that docker setup behaves, and I would like to understand how to work with it. The extension I would like to play with as a starting point is the "Web Hook" one from Magento Connect. When clicking "Install Extension", I'm given a link (`http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/GoMedia_Webhook`). What to do with that link?